# Values pass through request to other classes in node js

Tags: node.js, express, request, httprequest, node-modules

I am using mongoDB to store the document. In my http get request i pull the particular document record and save it request object to process on it(using middlewear). Later when there is any patch/put request come then i use the same request object and modify the paramater. But problem lies when  i want to use the previous request stored values after modifying in put/patch request. Even i tried to store in different variable under request parameter, but when i change anything on req values, all request values get modified. Below is chuck of code.

```
req.PreviousStoreData = _.head(data);  //data object
req.currentData = _.head(data);   // copy data object
req.currentData.status = req.body.status;
// now if try to see the PreviousStoreData then it also got modified with latest status (modified only in currentData param)
```

If anything not understood well, please ping me back

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign()`, like that:

```
req.PreviousStoreData = {};
Object.assign(req.PreviousStoreData, _.head(data));
req.currentData = _.head(data);
req.currentData.status = req.body.status;
```

By typing "=" you set a reference to an object, which is the same object that currentData uses. Changing this object will cause both values to change.

`Object.assign()` copies all parameters from a source object (last argument) to the destination objects (not-last arguments), so you're actually duplicating an object instead of referring to it.

Comment: Dint workout. Still its removing the past values with latest change. I tries with even a new variable 


`const storeData = Object.assign({}, req.mission );
    req.mission[stage] = req.body[stage];`

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign() does seem to be the way to go. But the first parameter needs to be an empty object, to be the source object so that you dont affect the reference.

```
req.PreviousStoreData = Object.assign({}, _.head(data));  
req.currentData = Object.assign({}, _.head(data));   
req.currentData.status = req.body.status;
```

Here you are duplicating the Object, rather than assigning it the reference.